# Python Minigame Not working correctly

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay, I am a very new Python Programmer, and I have only programmed in Lua before Python. I made a little word minigame to put into a large word game but it is not working as expected. Can somone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
NumberTimes = 0
from random import randint
while NumberTimes < 12:
 RandNum = randint(0,9)
 print RandNum
 Correct = raw_input("")
 if Correct == RandNum:
       print "Correct"
 if Correct != RandNum:
       print "YOU LOSE"
```

Instead of when you press the correct number, it prints you lose. and if you press the wrong number, it prints you lose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you need to convert the output of `raw_input("")` into `int()` before you check. The `raw_input("")` value is stored as string.

More info on [`raw_input` in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

> The function reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So, the code should be:

```
Correct = int(raw_input(""))
```

Also, just make sure you increment `NumberTimes` in the loop, or you will end up in an infinite loop

Comment: Thankyou very much! I understand now that I have to convert it from a string into an integer.

Comment: Glad it helped.. Just one more recommendation: use 4 spaces instead of 2 for indentation, as that is the recommended PEP8 standard.. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two problems:

1. It needs to convert the input to an integer before comparing it with the integer returned by `randint`.
2. It will run forever because `NumberTimes` never increments.

However, instead of using a while-loop and an incrementing variable, you can just use a for-loop:

```
from random import randint          # Import the 'randint' function
for _ in xrange(12):                # Loop 12 times
    RandNum = randint(0,9)          # Get a random integer
    print RandNum                   # Print it
    try:                            # Start a try/except block
        Correct = int(raw_input())  # Get the input as an integer         
        if Correct == RandNum:      # If it equals 'RandNum'...
            print "Correct"         # ...print "Correct"
        else:                       # Otherwise...
            print "YOU LOSE"        # ...print "YOU LOSE"
    except ValueError:              # But, if a ValueError is thrown...
        print "Bad input"           # ...then the input wasn't a number
```

For-loops run a certain piece of code a set number of times (in this case 12).

Answer (score 0):

`correct = int(raw_input(""))` is the main problem change it to that and then try